# Can't ssh from Windows 10 16.04

Tags: networking, ssh, windows-10

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 server on my local network (192.168.1.100). I can't ssh to the server from my windows 10 box using either putty or bitvise ssh client. I get a network error, connection timed out.

I can ssh to other computers on my network (a Mac for example). And other computers (non Windows 10) boxes can ssh to the .100 server.

Also, I have my router routing ssh calls to my external IP address to the .100 server. If I use my external IP or domain name I can ssh just fine.

From the Windows box, ping 192.168.1.100 works fine, as does tracert 192.168.1.100.

Any idea what to check on the Ubuntu side to help diagnose the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is ssh server setup in Ubuntu

Comment: `sshd`, the "SSH Server", sends log messages to `/var/log/auth.log` with older versions of the logs stored as `/var/log/auth.log*`. Read The Logs, Luke!

Comment: Checking the logs, there is no entry when I try to ssh to the server from the Windows 10 machine. So something is preventing access to port 22?